# R gbm - handling of missing values

Tags: r, boosting

I am trying to understand how gbm handles missing values.

I have seen this thread on the topic:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718648/r-gbm-handling-of-missing-values

But it focusses on explaining how the results show how missing values are treated.  What I am interested in is how the algorithm treats missing values when fitting the trees.  E.g. does it consider a missing value to contain information, or does it essentially ignore that feature?

I have not been able to find this information online so any responses would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might get better response on an R-specific site.

Comment: Some data can be imputed using an r package, and in other scenarios the data can be ignored or treated as Zero. I know that in Matlab, depending on how you handle the import it will fill with zeroes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update - the gbm package builds trees with three splits (left node, right node, and missing node).  Therefore the model treats the missing values as a separate group.

This is explained in the gbm.object documentation, in the section on c.splits:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gbm/versions/2.1.1/topics/gbm.object

Comment: I suggest adding a source for that, perhaps the manual or a whitepaper of the package mentions it :)